# what means ${demo.css} in example files of highcharts ? That piece of code seems to be literal

Tags: highcharts

what means ${demo.css} in example files of highcharts ? That piece of code

```
<style type="text/css"> 
${demo.css}     
</style>
```

seems to be literal

Comment: Where did you see this? Looks like some templating engine is being used.

Comment: Could you give more specific information about your issue? The best would be live example of this code.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a jQuery template tag to load a non-existent CSS file. According to [this Highcharts form post](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/editing-the-css-for-a-chart-t32009/) it is not required, and all configuration should be managed through Javascript rather than CSS.

The [Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) lists all of the Javascript configuration items.

Comment: nice explanation.